# Segmentation fault when attempting to edit a struct's data in an array of struct pointers

Tags: c, adjacency-list

I have an array of pointers to represent a Graph as an Adjacency Table and can set these pointers to new Node pointers without issue by running the following code:

```
    typedef struct node
    {
        int pageNum;
        int numLinks;
        struct node *next;
    } Node;

    int main(...) {
        Node *linkedListArray[n];
        Node *newNode;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                linkedListArray[i] = NULL;
            }

        newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

        newNode->pageNum = token2;
        newNode->next = linkedListArray[token1];
        newNode->numLinks = 0;
        linkedListArray[token1] = newNode;

        setNumLinks(linkedListArray);
}
```

Once this Graph is created I need to iterate through each linked list in the array and update the numLinks variable for the head of the head pointer for each element in the array to the number of links in the linked list. I created the following function to perform this task:

```
void setNumLinks(Node *array[]) {
    int linkCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Node *curPtr = array[i];
        while (curPtr != NULL) {
            linkCount++;
            curPtr = curPtr->next;
        }
        array[i]->numLinks = linkCount; //This is the line that causes a  Seg Fault
        linkCount = 0;
    }
}
```

I thought the above line would be valid however it causes a Segmentation Fault. I have a nearly identical function to the one above that prints the contents of the Adjacency List that works perfectly so the issue is with updating pointers' values in the array. Can someone please explain why it causes the fault and how to fix it? Thanks for the help!

Edit:
token1 and token2 are the positive integer representation of a node, e.g. 0, 5
Here's a sample of the print function's output

```
0: 891835 -> 867923 -> 824020 -> 11342 # Links = 0
1: 893884 -> 862566 -> 748615 -> 635575 -> 569212 -> 552600 -> 276233 -> 223236 -> 203402 -> 53051 # Links = 0
2: 858904 -> 644135 -> 597621 -> 581609 -> 565424 -> 472889 -> 462435 -> 430119 -> 423174 -> 357310 -> 30957 # Links = 0
3: 
4: 795253 -> 746182 -> 670449 -> 173976 -> 79146 -> 62391 -> 44695 # Links = 0
5: 608321 -> 581741 -> 579655 -> 535142 -> 300279 -> 219773 -> 39733 # Links = 0
6: 668992 -> 188708 -> 119755 # Links = 0
7: 877041 -> 747035 -> 743269 -> 694921 -> 514170 -> 507854 -> 487767 -> 358176 -> 230497 -> 226374 -> 174836 -> 86833 -> 75039 -> 57818 -> 43343 -> 19576 # Links = 0
8: 846855 -> 55948 # Links = 0
9: 780043 -> 721062 -> 704303 -> 504263 # Links = 0
10: 826668 -> 556796 -> 393685 -> 332640 -> 310676 -> 194746 -> 181848 -> 134964 -> 129774 -> 85506 -> 49988 # Links = 0
11: 881590 -> 852008 -> 579432 -> 400675 -> 360442 -> 280605 -> 216203 -> 160306 -> 105322 -> 75364 -> 42021 # Links = 0
12: 844958 # Links = 0
13: 909316 -> 908351 -> 876328 -> 845262 -> 834531 -> 832457 -> 806291 -> 756408 -> 677378 -> 514176 -> 487593 -> 379868 -> 317571 -> 298314 -> 257316 -> 143673 -> 104279 # Links = 0
14: 
15: 888999 -> 859227 -> 830774 -> 795462 -> 771890 -> 661693 -> 639906 -> 567443 -> 518054 -> 460382 -> 451817 -> 422877 -> 390257 -> 371984 -> 268368 -> 130698 -> 99387 -> 44788 -> 43847 -> 16586 # Links = 0
16: 644379 # Links = 0
17: 876722 -> 861125 -> 859607 -> 793999 -> 725759 -> 724847 -> 691178 -> 647961 -> 590190 -> 551829 -> 546581 -> 520215 -> 501061 -> 202339 -> 116209 -> 96828 -> 40033 -> 33881 # Links = 0
18: 886971 -> 818382 -> 781983 -> 528720 -> 445245 -> 431311 -> 225879 # Links = 0
19: 653863 -> 173976 -> 170194 # Links = 0
20: 908351 -> 7235 # Links = 0
```

Comment: `Node *linkedListArray[n];`  what is the value of `n` here?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you sure `array[i]` will never be `NULL`?

Comment: In this instance the value of n is 916425 and I am certain that array[i] won't be NULL in this instance because I can run a nearly identical print function that iterates through every linked list in the array and prints every edge pair.

Comment: Are you *really* certain that `array[i]` won't be `NULL`? Doesn't lines like `3: ` and `14: ` suggest that some elements of `array` (`array[3]` and `array[14]`) are `NULL`?

Comment: Thank you @MikeCAT for helping me out. I took your advice and looked at the values of array[i] and found out they are NULL for certain values. I assumed they would never be null but forgot that my dataset of edges is not complete. Sorry I didn't catch that in my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    linkedListArray[token1] = newNode;
```

Here, you are assigning only one element of `linkedListArray`. Remaining all elements of `linkedListArray` are still `NULL`.  But you are accessing other elements in the function.

```
     array[i]->numLinks = linkCount;
```

This will cause segmentation fault, for `i!=token1`. In this case `array[i] = NULL`, so you will get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that the dataset of edges I was using is not complete meaning some indices would have NULL values in them. I just had to add an if clause to check for NULL values of array[i].